# How to create a 3D surface from given coordinates with python?

Tags: python, 3d, interpolation, spline

I have some discrete coordinates with their heights and I need to create a smooth surface which I will continue to use. I need to have heights for all the coordinates in that surface. I was considering using a 3D spline but I am having trouble applying the methods suggested in comparable kind of questions. I am not an experienced programmer so I would probably find any suggestions helpful. Please forgive me if I may asked something very similar to what was already discussed before. I am using Python 3.6.

EDIT

I made a tiny list (similar to what I have).

```
Z=[]
Z.append([20.2, 20.1, 35])
Z.append([20.1, 24.5, 36])
Z.append([21.0, 23.2, 33])
Z.append([22.3, 20.0, 34])
Z.append([22.3, 19.5, 28])
Z.append([20.1, 19.5, 27])
Z.append([20.1, 24.6, 31])
Z.append([22.3, 24.6, 32])
```

The first number here represents longitude, the second - latitude and the third - altitude. I need to make a "surface" (not necessarily to plot it) which would contain the information about all the coordinates in between this rectangle.

I believe this could sound unclear but maybie the problem is that I do not know the exact structure or the type of data I am looking for.

Comment: Please have a look here: [ask]

Comment: I changed the question (if that was the problem). Thak you for the correction.

Comment: please provide with some examples, inputs, outputs, just text isn't helping us either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use method `griddata` from scipy.

Here is small example how to use neareast neighbour interpolation method with your data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
# --------------------
Z=[]
Z.append([20.2, 20.1, 35])
Z.append([20.1, 24.5, 36])
Z.append([21.0, 23.2, 33])
Z.append([22.3, 20.0, 34])
Z.append([22.3, 19.5, 28])
Z.append([20.1, 19.5, 27])
Z.append([20.1, 24.6, 31])
Z.append([22.3, 24.6, 32])
# ---------------------------
xin=np.array(Z)[:,0];
yin=np.array(Z)[:,1];
zin=np.array(Z)[:,2];
# ----------------------------
xout=np.linspace(20.,23.,10);
yout=np.linspace(19.,25.,10);
xout,yout = np.meshgrid(xout,yout);
# ----------------------------
zout=griddata((xin,yin),zin,(xout,yout),'nearest');
# -----------------------------
from pylab import pcolormesh,show
pcolormesh(xout,yout,zout);show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one additional question: could I get for example the height of the specific coordinates longitude = 21.4 and latitude = 22.5 and how would I do that?

Comment: You should find the indices, where the coordinates match or are close to your desired locations: `kkx=np.where(np.abs(xout-21.4)==np.abs(xout-21.4).min())` and `kky=np.where(np.abs(yout-22.5)==np.abs(yout-22.5).min())`. Then you can easily get the value: `zval = zout[kky,kkx]`